# Use of de Moivre's Theorem and Euler's formula to solve an expression

Tags: trigonometry

Let $n$ be a natural number, the Show that $$(\cos(2)+i\sin(2)+1)^n=2^{n}\cos^n(1)(\cos(n)+i\sin(n))$$

The use of Euler's formula and de Moivre's Theorem isn't succeeding. Does anyone have a hint for how I should proceed?

EDIT: Thank you all. There was a typo in the textbook, which is why I was struggling.

Comment: What is $z$ in the LHS?? How you arrived to a $n$ in RHS??

Comment: Presumably you have a typo. in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
2^n\cos^n(1)(\cos(n)+i\sin(n))=2^n\cos^n(1)(\cos(1)+i\sin(1))^n
=(2\cos(1)\cos(1)+i2\cos(1)\sin(1))^n=(2\cos^2(1)+i\sin(2))^n=(\cos(2)+i\sin(2)+1)^n
$$

Answer (score 0):

Put $$1=\cos (2n \pi)$$ in your LHS then
$$(1+\cos(z)+i\sin(z))^{n}=(\cos (2n \pi)+\cos(z)+i\sin(z))^{n}$$

Then proceed to write as exponential.